# Looking for a more elegant solution to this loop

Tags: php, algorithm, math

I tried asking this earlier, but I don't think I phrased the question correctly so I worked out something that got me the result I was after and now am hoping that it will help someone help me.

**Problem:** I have 10 items. If you buy 1, it's $10. I will sell you the second one for $9. I will sell you the third item for $8. I will keep taking off money until we get to $5/item because that is the lowest I will sell it for. So, if you buy all 10, it will cost you $65.

This is the pricing model I am trying to achieve, except at a much larger scale. Instead of a handful of items using dollars, I'm talking about up to millions and using fractions of pennies.

This is my current code:

```
<?php 

function getCost($num_items)
{
    $min_price            = 0.002;
    $max_price            = 0.007;
    $discount_range       = 1000000;

    $discount_per_additional_item = ($max_price - $min_price) / ($discount_range - 1);

    $price_per_unit = MAX($min_price, ($max_price - ($num_items - 1) * $discount_per_additional_item) );

    return $price_per_unit;
}

$array = [100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 200000, 300000, 400000, 500000, 600000, 700000, 800000, 900000, 1000000];

foreach ($array as $value)
{

    $sum = 0;
    for ($i = 0; $i < $value; ++$i)
        $sum += getCost($i);

    echo number_format($value) . '  |  $' . number_format($sum) . "\n";

}
```

Which results in:

```
100  |  $1
1,000  |  $7
10,000  |  $70
100,000  |  $675
200,000  |  $1,300
300,000  |  $1,875
400,000  |  $2,400
500,000  |  $2,875
600,000  |  $3,300
700,000  |  $3,675
800,000  |  $4,000
900,000  |  $4,275
1,000,000  |  $4,500
```

I'm using $array as a sanity check where in the real world, I would simply calculate for the actual number the customer is being charged for.

My question is: Is there a way to accomplish this without using a for loop? Something, perhaps, more elegant?

I made an example online: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/47e270dbad8cbe16c9ea906ffd2dce098a52fbca

Comment: What do you dislike about the for loop? I see nothing wrong with it

Comment: Question: what is the purpose of `$sum` in your code? why does the result of `100` matter with the result of `1000`? If you are selling `100` toys, then that value should be enough to find the discount for `100`, and if your selling `100,000` toys, then you shouldn't need to know the price at which you sold `100` toys in order to calculate the dicounted price of `100,000` toys.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton it seems to me that the OP is concerned with the number of loop cycles performed on the higher numbers

Comment: As you are talking about money, i would be careful about using floating point values, due to rounding errors. I suspect the accountants will not be happy?

Comment: Note that for `$i=0` `getCost($i);` will return a value above the max price. I guess you want to start your loop at 1, or else change the formula. That depends on whether that argument means how many you bought before, or the number of the item you are buying.

Comment: I'd like to not have to use a loop because I need to be able to run this function several times a second (preferably in javascript) for the type of front-end I am building and as you can see, it's not very fast.

Comment: Seems odd to have a tiered pricing structure where, for example, item number 500,002 is slightly less expensive than item number 500,001. Do you really need that level of pricing complexity?

Comment: @MikeBrant In this case it makes sense, yes. I am not charging for something where the user can purchase more than they need in order to get a discount. I want to reward people with larger purchases, but that reward should be proportionate to the purchase. A tiered pricing structure in my case would do more to punish users with smaller accounts than it would to reward users with large accounts.

Comment: i dont think php is a particularly good choice for algorithmic trading ^^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code will have the same output, and does not have the inner loop:

```
$min_price            = 0.002;
$max_price            = 0.007;
$discount_range       = 1000000;
$discount_per_additional_item = ($max_price - $min_price)/($discount_range - 1);

$num_progressively_discounted_items = 
        ceil(($max_price - $min_price) / $discount_per_additional_item);
foreach ($array as $value) {
    $num_items_above_min = min($value, $num_progressively_discounted_items);
    $num_items_at_min = $value - $num_items_above_min; 
    $sum = $num_items_at_min * $min_price + 
           $num_items_above_min * $max_price - 
           $discount_per_additional_item 
               * $num_items_above_min * ($num_items_above_min - 1)/2;

    echo number_format($value) . '  |  $' . number_format($sum) . "\n";
}
```

This is what it does:

- It first checks how many times the unit discount can be subtracted from the original price before hitting the minimum price. If more than the number of items you are buying, then this calculated figure is corrected to that number of items.
- The remaining number of items (if any) are also taken note of: these will all have the minimum price.
- The sum consists of two parts. The easy part is represented by the number of items that will go for the minimum price, and it is a simple multiplication.
- The second part of the sum consists of an always decreasing term, or otherwise put: it is the maximum price for the number of items that don't go for the minimum price, minus the sum of `0+1+2+3+4+5...+n`. For that the formula is known: `n(n-1)/2`.

Like I mentioned in comments, there is something strange in your code: for `$i=0` the value returned by `getCost($i)` is higher than the max price, as the unit discount gets added to it. This can be corrected by starting your inner loop with `$i=1`. Anyway, this means there is a tiny difference in the result of my proposed code, as it does not have this peculiarity. But as the discount per unit is so tiny, you don't actually notice it in the printed output.

Comment: I like this but if `$discount_range` is always 1,000,000 then would it make sense to statically assign 999,999 instead of calculating `($discount_range - 1)` a million times? I am personally still trying to decipher OPs objective so it's quite possible I am not understanding something. In fact, `$discount_per_additional_item` could be statically assigned.

Comment: Indeed, in this answer I assumed that for one batch of items, the unit discount is constant, which is the case in the OP's code. Note that I put the calculation of `$discount_per_additional_item` out of the loop for that reason: it always yields the same result.

Comment: Thank you. This is so much faster.

Comment: @trincot mathematically speaking, when you do `$discount_per_additional_item = ($max_price - $min_price)/($discount_range - 1);` and then do `($max_price - $min_price) / $discount_per_additional_item)`, you are just getting back `($discount_range - 1)`. I think there is no need for this particular calculation.

Comment: Indeed, I did this so there is liberty to change the way `$discount_per_additional_item` is calculated without having to touch the body of the loop, but also to avoid too much impact of floating point inaccuracy. In other words, I take `$discount_per_additional_item` to be the truth, and ignore the existence of `$discount_range`. still, I could calculate that before the loop ...

Comment: So, I have put the calculation of the maximum number of items that will progressively be discounted (not minimum price) just before the loop. That should save a (tiny) amount of execution time. It may seem overkill to not just take `$discount_range-1`, but this way you can easily change the formula for `$discount_per_additional_item` without having to change anything else.

Comment: @trincot, Translated to JS, your code is more than fast enough for my purposes. Thank you again. http://codepen.io/Greg-J/pen/reXKgB?editors=1010

Answer (score 0):

You can do this a little bit more **functional style**:

```
function sumOfNaturalSeries($n)
{
    return ((1 + $n) / 2) * $n;
}

$minPrice = 0.002;
$maxPrice = 0.007;
$discountRange = 1000000;

$discountStep = ($maxPrice - $minPrice) / $discountRange;

$getPrice = function ($numberOfItems) use (
    $minPrice,
    $maxPrice,
    $discountRange,

    $discountStep
) {
    if ($numberOfItems <= $discountRange) {
        return $maxPrice * $numberOfItems - sumOfNaturalSeries($numberOfItems - 1) * $discountStep;
    }

    $itemsAboveRange = $numberOfItems - $discountRange;

    return $maxPrice * $discountRange - sumOfNaturalSeries($discountRange - 1) * $discountStep + $minPrice * $itemsAboveRange;
};

$array = [100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 200000, 300000, 400000, 500000, 600000, 700000, 800000, 900000, 1000000];

$sums = array_map($getPrice, $array);

var_dump($sums);
var_dump(array_map('number_format', $sums));
```

Here is [demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4e9049da817bea658812afe669f14ba8834590bb).

**Take a notice on computational error.**